# Flask service down after 200 concurrent access in cloud foundry

Tags: python, flask, cloud-foundry, stress-testing

So i build a flask app that only do select from database using cx_oracle and deploy it on pivotal cloud foundry. And my team did a stress test on it, but it down at 200 concurrent use hit. Is there anyone know what happened? i doubt that it was a performance issue, because the app only do select from db. I didnt do any customization on the flask, but i also use flask-restful

thanks

Comment: you need to post the code since it's difficult to find out the issue without any reference to the configuration and/or code.

Comment: also, post the output of `cf events` (after the app fails) and capture `cf logs` while the app is being load tested. Both can provide more clues.